# How can I get Generic injection entities use Class and generic class name in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, generics

I only have two determine the type，one of is my Basic Class, another is generic class name.

```
BasicOrmDao.class;
Class cls = Class.forName("com.base.Role");
```

My injection class is

```
class RoleDao extends BasicOrmDao<Role> {
}
```

I don't know bean name roleDao, because of it maybe BasicOrmDao.

So how can I get my bean **"roleDao"** use `BasicOrmDao.class` and `String name = "com.base.Role";`.

I want use java code to do this, like @Autowired, but I only known basic type BasicOrmDao, and generic class name "com.base.Role"

Comment: How are your beans defined? To where are you intending to inject them?

Comment: I want use java code to do this, like @Autowired, but I only known basic type BasicOrmDao, and generic class name "com.base.Role".